# How to save the old state of an array before shuffling

Tags: javascript, arrays, fisher-yates-shuffle

I have an array of 50 objects as elements.

Each object contains an array of 4 elements:

```
var all = [{
    question: "question 1 goes here",
    options: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}, ... {
    question: "question 50",
    options: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}]
```

I want to select 10 elements randomly and save to two other arrays, one of the array I want to shuffle options. but when shuffling both arrays are affected.

```
var selected = [];
var shuffled = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length);
    selected.push(all[rand]);
    shuffled.push(all[rand]);
    all.splice(rand, 1);

    for(let j = 3; j > 0; j--) {
        let rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * j);
        [
             shuffled[i].options[j], 
             shuffled[i].options[rand2]
        ] = [
             shuffled[i].options[rand2],
             shuffled[i].options[j]
        ];
    }
}
console.log(selected); // is shuffled too
console.log(shuffled);
```

How do I prevent that?

I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple, but I can't spot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new instances for the chosen objects and their `options` arrays:

```js
// shuffle array a in place (Fisher-Yates)
// optional argument len (=a.length):
//   reduced shuffling: shuffling is done for the first len returned elements only, 
//   array a will be shortened to length len.
function shuffle(a, len=a.length){
 for(let m=a.length,n=Math.min(len,m-1),i=0,j;i<n;i++){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*(m-i)+i);
  if (j-i) [ a[i],a[j] ] = [ a[j],a[i] ]; // swap 2 array elements
 }
 a.length=len;
 return a;
}

const all=[...new Array(50)].map((_,i)=>({question:"Question "+(i+1), options:["A","B","C","D"]}));

const selected = shuffle([...all],10), // return first 10 shuffled elements only!
      shuffled = selected.map(o=>({...o,options:shuffle([...o.options])}));

console.log(selected) // is no longer shuffled!
console.log(shuffled);
```

I consigned the shuffle algorithm to a separate function (`shuffle()`) and applied it twice: first to the `all` array to make sure we don't get any duplicates in our "random" selection and then to the `options` arrays contained within their sliced-off objects. The function `shuffle(a,len)` sorts array `a` in place. I made it return the array reference again purely out of convenience, as it helps me keep my code more compact. The optional argument `len` will cause the array `a` to be shortened to `len` shuffled elements (still "in place": the input array will be affected too!).

So, in order to preserve my "input" arrays I created new array instances each time I called the function by applying the `...` operator:

```
shuffled = shuffle([...all],10);
...
shuffle([...o.options])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spread function that makes a hard copy from you object `all`

```js
var selected = [];
var shuffled = [];

// Make a copy of all by using the spread function:
// You can later use this variable since it will contain the content of the 
// initial all variable
const allCopy = [...all];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length);
  selected.push(all[rand]);
  shuffled.push(all[rand]);
  all.splice(rand, 1);

  for (let j = 3; j > 0; j--) {
    let rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * j);
    [shuffled[i].options[j], shuffled[i].options[rand2]] = [shuffled[i].options[rand2], shuffled[i].options[j]];
  }
}
console.log(selected); // is shuffled too
console.log(shuffled);
```

Comment: I just tried it but both arrays still keeps shuffling